# Are comments searchable?

Tags: support

I remember great comments on questions here to which I'd like to point.

It's easy enough to get the URL of a given comment. The problem is to find great comments back. Are comments searchable (if yes, how) and if not, can be made?

Comment: Google might be able to find them; I don't think SE's search feature will find them by design. If they're especially highly voted, you might be able to write a SQL query to return the highest voted comments on CV at the SE data site.

Comment: @gung: no, unfortunately the ones I see are often made on questions that don't get any answer and aren't not close, so they tend not to get a lot of traffic.

Comment: It probably wouldn't work then. (Note, however, that I meant looking for *comments* that have been upvoted, not comments on *questions* that have been upvoted.)

Comment: yea these are simple comments on badly thought out questions. That's why these questions don't get answers/traffic/vote and this low traffic means the comments themselves don't get many upvotes.

Comment: It might be of your interest to follow this thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183142/ability-to-search-comments-would-be-useful

Answer (score 6):

To answer your direct question: nope, comments are not searchable (currently) by the in-house search feature. I believe Google looks at *all* text on the page, including comments, but there isn't a way to limit searching to comments only.

That said, if your SQL is pretty good, you can use [Data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com) and search comment text for any graduated site.